# Problem with css/sass in a box with multiples elements

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, sass

im having a problem, i build this image:

[box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lb2L.png)

as you can see its a box with 4 elements inside. Its looks fine but when i start to re-size the windows it become a mess. idk what proporty im doing wrong, but i gonna give you a .gif of what is happening

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1z2wC.jpg

this is what becomes when i re-zice
[THIS IS THE MESS WHEN I RE-SIZE THE WINDOW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PIQH.png)
this is my code:

html:

```
<div class="containerRebalance">
<div class= firstTittleRow1>
 <div class="iconwarning">
   <mat-icon  [ngStyle]="{'color':'#f06f0f'}">warning</mat-icon>
 </div>
<div class= secondTittleRow>
  <div class="textoWarning">
    Para enviar tu solicitud de modificación, es necesario
    que los porcentajes de participación por cada
    beneficiario sea mayor a cero y que la suma de las
    participaciones en cada prioridad sea igual al 100% 
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="linetext">
 <div class="texto1">
  <p class="texto1">
    ¿Desea repartir en partes iguales el porcentaje
    de participación de la  {{prioridad}}?
  </p>
 </div>

   <div class="texto2">
    Yes
  </div>
  <div class="texto2">
   No
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

---

SASS

```
.texto1
  float: left
  margin-top: -1px
  margin-left: 12px
  font-size: 14px
  line-height: 21px
  font-family: "Titillium Web", sans-serif
  font-weight: 400
  color: rgb(96, 110, 125)
.texto2
  font-size: 14px
  line-height: 21px
  font-family: "Titillium Web", sans-serif
  font-weight: 400
  color: rgb(96, 110, 125)
  float: right
  padding-right: 55px

.iconwarning
  float: left
  padding-top: 24px

.firstTittleRow1
  padding-left: 10px
  height: 73px
  display: block

.linetext
  display: block

.textoWarning
  font-size: 14px
  line-height: 18px
  font-family: "Titillium Web", sans-serif
  font-weight: 400
  color: rgb(96, 110, 125)
  padding-top: 20px




.secondTittleRow
  display: flex
  padding-left: 10px
  height: 73px
.containerRebalance
    height: 113px
    background: #fdf6e9
    border: 1px solid #f9ce93
    color: #4d5966
    font-size: 0.75rem
    font-family: Roboto-Medium
    align-items: center
    padding: 0 0.9375rem
    line-height: 17px
    margin-top: 48px
    padding-bottom: 1px
```

How can i make to not look like that? and keep the order of that 4 elements inside, i dont mind if the buttoms go down but keep the order in the main square. ty very much

Comment: It's not clear what you want, what do you mean by "it becomes a mess"? please make a codepen that includes your SASS code, and it helps if you upload images of both what you want to achieve and what goes wrong.

Comment: @Aras i added a image just now , its show how its a "mess"

Comment: This link does not load for me
https://imgur.com/VZQAKFY

Comment: @Aras sorry, im new to imgur and idk how to make it public, but in the image i post it you can see whats happen when i re-size

Comment: you added a fixed height of 73px to firstTittleRow1, it's preventing the element to grow as its content breaks into more lines, again it's really hard to debug a code like this. try removing the height or change it to min-height if you have to.

Comment: @Aras already removed, but the problem still the same

Comment: secondTittleRow also has a fixed height
check out this pen I commented out the fixed heights:
https://codepen.io/irvash/pen/ExQMRPB

Comment: @Aras i removed it too, but look how the text goes outside the orange box: https://imgur.com/gallery/KZSestS

Comment: which class has the orange background?

Comment: sorry, my bad, i forgot to put the class, its the class that have all the code .containerRebalance , i already edited the code in the question, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove fixed heights from .containerRebalance, .secondTittleRow and .firstTittleRow1, and add display:flex to .containerRebalance

```
.containerRebalance
// height: 113px 'Remove This'
background: #fdf6e9
border: 1px solid #f9ce93
color: #4d5966
font-size: 0.75rem
font-family: Roboto-Medium
align-items: center
padding: 0 0.9375rem
line-height: 17px
margin-top: 48px
padding-bottom: 1px
display: flex

.firstTittleRow1
  padding-left: 10px
  // height: 73px 'Remove This'
  display: block

.secondTittleRow
  display: flex
  padding-left: 10px
  // height: 73px 'Remove This'
```

you can see it [here](https://codepen.io/irvash/pen/ExQMRPB)

Comment: i removed it too, but look how the text goes outside the orange box: imgur.com/gallery/KZSestS

Comment: thanks! now its works almost 100%, we hare in a 95%, the last problem i have is the buttoms "yes" and "now", how can i make in the moment they break line and got one of top of another, they could move to the next line (only when they are no longer next to each other), like this example? : https://imgur.com/a/IWGaNh5

Comment: your imgur links do not load

Comment: i think now you can see it : https://imgur.com/gallery/IWGaNh5

Comment: check out the pen I fixed it. Remove floats from both buttons and wrap them inside a div

Comment: yeah, but i only need they to be like that when no more space availeable and they go up into anoter, if we have space the "yes" and "no" button should be always like this: https://imgur.com/gallery/qtTWFKZ , if no more space, and they start to collapse and put one up above the other, then they should be like your last edit in the pen

Comment: do you have telegram?

Comment: i have whatsapp and instagram, i can download telegram

Comment: i already downloaded telegram

Comment: I don't have whatsapp and instagram won't do the job. Install telegram desktop if possible and comment your ID, I'll text you then we can chat

Comment: my user name is @PaimonDeluxe

Comment: i cant find you, its other place where i can meet you? maybe discord?

Comment: it should've worked, let me see if discord works , it's banned here :|

Comment: how about a gmail?

Comment: I sent you an invite in gmail, also texted you in telegram